# Confusion about the Memory Use of Xcode,the Real Memory of Activity Monitor

Tags: ios, memory

I would like to test APP in the process of running the physical memory occupied, the first way is to use xcode debugging APP, Memory Report shows real-time occupied physical memory, **only about 90 MB**; The second way to use Activity Monitor detection APP, In the Detail-> Summary-> Samples Real Memory display **up to 200MB or so**.
So I am confused, which value can really represent APP physical memory occupied?

[Xcode Memory Use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Phg.png)

[AM Real Mem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vn8v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iOS app can be using 90 megs of actual RAM but it will typically have a lot more space as memory mapped files. These could be shared libraries or just files that you explicitly mmap. While iOS will kill your app if you use too much RAM memory, you can actually use quite a bit more mmap memory, up to about 650 Megs without getting a memory warning. The readout showing memory use directly in Xcode is your best readout for active RAM memory.

Comment: Thanks! So I would like to ask that: Real Memory(200M) in the AM is wrong?,and it contains what? As far as I know the mmap file and shared libraries should also be in RAM memory.

Comment: Shared files can be mapped into memory, but not allocated by your app. That is why they can be "shared", since system libraries can be loaded without inflating memory use of your specific app. Just be concerned with the ram allocated by your app.